# Cursor Not Changing on GridSplitter - Community Toolkit

Tags: winui-3, windows-community-toolkit, gridsplitter

Trying out the Community Toolkit GridSplitter, but the cursor does not change when I hover over the splitter bar. Changing the GripperCursor or CursorBehavior properties has no effect.  It stays with the default cursor.

It resizes the panes when clicked and dragged, but the mouse cursor does not behave as expected.

I am using packages
WindowsAppSDK  1.3.2305,
CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI  7.1.2 and
CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.Layout 7.1.2

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="AppPrototypes.Views.GridSplitter"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AppPrototypes.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    >

    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition MinHeight="100"  />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition MinHeight="100"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Margin=" 10 10 0 0" Text="Top Row.    
                       This text to simulate the resizing feature of the Grid" />
        </Grid>
        
        <controls:GridSplitter Grid.Row="1"
            GripperCursor="UniversalNo"
            CursorBehavior="ChangeOnGripperHover"  />

        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <TextBlock Text="Bottom Row.     
                       This text to simulate the resizing feature of the Grid" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I guess the cursor of the `GridSplitter` [doesn't work](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/4591#issuecomment-1178068548) on WinUI 3 apps.

You should try the `GridSplitter` from the [CommunityToolkit.Labs.WinUI.SizerBase](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Labs-Windows/issues/101) NuGet package. I can confirm that its cursor works.

1. Add a new NuGet package source.

   Feed URL: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dotnet/CommunityToolkit/_packaging/CommunityToolkit-Labs/nuget/v3/index.json
2. Temporarily, disable other package sources, including *nuget.org*.
   I don't know why but I couldn't install the *CommunityToolkit.Labs.WinUI.SizerBase* with other sources enabled.
3. Enable *Include prerelease*.
4. Add the *CommunityToolkit.Labs.WinUI.SizerBase* package.

And use it like this:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="GridSplitterExample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.Labs.WinUI"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:GridSplitterExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition MinHeight="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition MinHeight="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock
                Margin="10,10,0,0"
                Text="Top Row." />
        </Grid>

        <controls:GridSplitter
            Grid.Row="1"
            Cursor="UniversalNo" />

        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <TextBlock Text="Bottom Row." />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew!  That version of GridSplitter worked as expected.  I also had to disable the CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.Layout package before it would work.